# Trying to write a next() method to iterate over a linked list and getting a "'NoneType' object is not callable" error

Tags: python, loops, linked-list, iterator, nodes

I'm trying to write a next method to be able to iterate over a linked list object with a for loop and no matter how I change my code I keep getting "'NoneType' object is not callable". It's an assignment and therefore I can't change anything when it comes to the other constructors and methods. Only thing I can play around with is iter and next. This is my code:

```
class Node:
    def  __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
       self.next = None



class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, fdata):
        firstNode = Node(fdata)
        self.first = firstNode
        self.last = firstNode
        self.n = 1

    def append(self, ndata):
        newNode = Node(ndata)
        self.last.next = newNode
        self.last = newNode
        self.next = None
        self.n += 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.__current.next == None:
           raise StopIteration
        else:        
           self.__current = self.__current.next
           return self.__current.next.ndata


a = LinkedList(0); a.append(1); a.append(2)

for n in a:
    print n
```

Comment: Note, your linked-list class shouldn't be the iterator, you should implement another iterator class, i.e. only implement `__iter__` in LinkedList, which should return a `LinkedListIterator` objec t, which implements `__iter__` and `next`. But anyway, what is `self.__current`? You never initialize it anywhere

Comment: More importantly, if you are getting an error, post the full error message, including calling code, and the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you advance reading too far.  Try:

```
self.__current = self.__current.next
return self.__current.data
```

Because `self.__current.next` at then moment will point to next-next element. And in case of list dnid - to nowhere.